# Having trouble with cloudinary file upload in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cloudinary

I am trying to upload image on cloudinary using nodeJs

**This is my code**

```
router.post('/imageUpload', upload.single('file'), function(req,res){

 User.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){
   if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {

    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path,
     {public_id:user.username},
     function(result){
     console.log(result)
     });
    }
   })  
 });
```

**My issue is that ,I am able to upload image on cloudinary file with custom name,but in console it does not loging result(i.e image) object**

*Instead of that it is returning*

> undefined

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dev-express-uploader package.

Comment: rcstraus is right, you cloudinary upload use 2 parameter, error and result. This mean that the callback is not an override function. So you should use booth of parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to console log the error and since you're having a successful upload, its undefined.

Try the following-

`function(error, result) {console.log(error, result);`